# Adding user remote when Windows trust relationship is broken

Tags: windows, dns, relationship

I had an error: `'Windows trust relationship between domain controller and client machine is broken'`
I don't remember local user account/password on remote computer.

i tried to use pstools for create new user on remote computer but it's not working.
Can i do it remote in other way?
In the end i want to repair Windows trust relationship. Can i do it without rejoin to domain?

Edit: I can't even restart remote computer via Powershell : `RPC server is unaviable`

Comment: The only way I can think of is to rejoin the client to the domain using local user account.

Comment: So i need to create new user local on 'broken' computer? And there is no other way to do it remotely?

Comment: You can try to go in to Active Directory and find the client and right click-> Reset Account. That might do the job.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't help:(

Comment: Did you restart the client?

Comment: I'm out of ideas...sorry